# What does 'that's how' means?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

In that sentence 'That's how you showed up?' **"That's how"** is some kind of exclamation? Give me a definition of this structure.

Comment: Are you asking us for an answer or commanding us?

Comment: We need more context to understand why the expression is being used.

Answer (score 1):

The normal structure of that sentence would be "is that how you showed up?". (referring to to a prior explanation.

However in your case, "that" and "is" are inverted, to put more emphasis on the word "that", making it more of an exclamation.

An example to clarify, would be:

"Is that what you want to put in the dish?" - Question if that particular ingredient out of many is the one to add.

"That's what you want to put in the dish?" - Incredulity that you want to put that particular ingredient into the dish.